# Extending root partition

Tags: command-line

I have installed Ubuntu server 16.4 using entire disk with LVM and when I tried to install Ubuntu-Desktop from command line, it failed in middle saying there isn't enough space. I am quite new to linux. I need to increase root partition from command-line so that i can install Desktop and other software. Please help me how to go about it in simplest way.

Comment: I haven't done this, but take a look at this: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/resize-existing-and-add-another-partition-with-lvm-316813/